# RTL8723DE Working with signal, but never connects

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I have signal, but wifi never connects. I use kubuntu 19.04. I tried to follow this steps.

```
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new

sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

And works to show my wifi icon, but I`cant connect (obviusly I put my password).

Then I tried:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

But nothing.

What hapend whit this wifi card? Why is so hard to configure?

Answer (score 9):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf <<< "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2"
```

and reboot.

If this doesn't help, try `ant_sel=1`.

Your laptop has only one wireless antenna connected to the wireless adapter. The adapter is designed to work with one or two antennas.

Auto selection of antennas doesn't work in Linux drivers. So you need to tell the driver which antenna is in use.

If a wrong one is selected, you have very low signal. The adapter can see access points, but the signal is not enough to connect.

This command creates a config file that sets the antenna 2 to be in use.

Comment: Perfect!. Is working!. So, why I need to do this?

Comment: I'll add an explanation.